# Testing if "i" is not "x" or "y" (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to check if "i" is not equal to "test" or "test2". If I set "i" to str("test") or str("test2) then it will say "i is not test or test2", and if I set "i" to something else like str("x") it functions normally.

```
    if str(i) != str("test") or str("test2"):
      print ("i is not test or test2")
    else:
      print ("i is test or test2")
```

Comment: Use a list: `str(i) not in [ str("test"), str("test2") ]`

Comment: Also, `'test'` is already a `str` so `str("test")` is a no-op ... albeit expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `or` statement doesn't works like that, `or` operator requires `boolean`  as the two operands, but in your case, the `or` is applied to a `boolnea` and `str` operator. The Python doesn't raises exception in this case, and internally converts the `str` to `True` value and processes the `or` operand.

Now you have two options, either you rectify your if statement as:

```
if str(i) != str("test") or str(i) !=str("test2"):
    print ("i is neither test not test2")
```

Or you may use:

```
if str(i) not in {str("test"), str("test2")}:
    print ("i is neither test not test2")
```

Comment: `print ("i is neither 'test' nor 'test2'")`.

Comment: @danihp hahahha, didn't tried to correct the vocab though.

Comment: Nice use of `set`, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if str(i) != "test" and str(i) != "test2":
      print ("i is not test or test2")
    else:
      print ("i is test or test2")
```

Comment: This post looks more like a comment than ans answer. Answer can't be a simple "try this", should be elaborate and explaining why doesn't works. If you are so lazy to do it, like me, just post a comment. Also, be accurate, where it says `"i is not test or test2"` should be `"i is not test neither test2"`.

Comment: You need `and` here -- logic doesn't work the same way English does.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mr @danihp, I was about to explain, but there is another answer better explaining what I was thinking of. I already gave it a thump up.

Comment: that is great Mr @GordonDavisson, I am editing it right now.

Comment: I just expained in a previous comment.
^_^